# Post() en R - Inegi

Tags: r, post

Soy nuevo en R  y deseo obtener mediante con una peticion POST al API de la INEGI los datos de 
Cálculo de Rutas.

> https://www.inegi.org.mx/servicios/Ruteo/Default.html#ApiInfo

En la documentación me dan la referencia

```
http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/sakbe_v3.1/libre 
http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/sakbe_v3.1/cuota 
http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/sakbe_v3.1/optima
```

Y los parámetros que deseo probar son estos

```
Parámetros
{
dest_i: 3345,
dest_f: 222,
v: 1,
type:"json",
proj:"MERC"
key:“<token>”
}
```

He intentado el siguiente codigo

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)


path <- "http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/sakbe_v3.1/optima"

parametros <- list(dest_i = 3345,
                   dest_f = 222,
                   v= 1,
                   type = "json",
                   proj ="MERC",
                   key = "kqvCNH1V-keUF-rSVa-O1tf-gdqFN6DynMNN")


request <- POST(path, query = parametros)
```

Pero no me da la respuesta esperada, nesecito una guia de como hacer correctamente la peticion y colocarla en un DATAFRAME.

Muchas Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar hay que recuperar el contenido del `response` mediante [`content()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.1/topics/content):

```
response <- POST(path, query = parametros)
contenido <- content(response, as = "parsed")
str(contenido)

List of 3
 $ data    :List of 6
  ..$ geojson     : chr "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[-11134099.7352654,1917591.27786769],[-11133898.689482,1917537."| __truncated__
  ..$ costo_caseta: num 709
  ..$ tiempo_min  : num 348
  ..$ advertencia : chr "La ruta incluye caminos de terracería."
  ..$ long_km     : num 495
  ..$ peaje       : chr "t"
 $ meta    :List of 1
  ..$ fuente: chr "INEGI, SAKBÉ Sistema de Ruteo de México v3.1, Red Nacional de Caminos Edición 2019"
 $ response:List of 2
  ..$ success: logi TRUE
  ..$ message: chr "OK"
```

Podemos ver que la variable `contenido` es una lista con los principales datos obtenidos del `POST`. Entiendo que cuando dices que quieres los datos en un  `data.frame` te refieres al los puntos de coordenadas, que se encuentran en `contenidos$data$geojson`, la forma más simple es leer la estructura `json`, obtener la lista `coordinates` y transformarla directo a un `data.frame`:

```
j <- jsonlite::fromJSON(contenido$data$geojson)
head(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, j$coordinates)))

         V1      V2
1 -11134100 1917591
2 -11133899 1917538
3 -11133764 1917502
4 -11133688 1917483
5 -11135048 1917840
6 -11134709 1917752
```

Pero en este caso al tratarse de coordenadas de lineas, puede que te interese mantener el número de línea, lo cual tampoco es muy complejo, si agregamos este dato a cada una de las matrices de la lista de coordenadas:

```
l <- lapply(1:length(j$coordinates), 
       function(x) { 
         m <- j$coordinates[[x]]
         matrix(c(rep(x, dim(m)[1]), m), ncol=3)
         }
       )

df_lineas <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))
colnames(df_lineas) <-  c("linea", "lon", "lat")
head(df_lineas)


  linea       lon     lat
1     1 -11134100 1917591
2     1 -11133899 1917538
3     1 -11133764 1917502
4     1 -11133688 1917483
5     2 -11135048 1917840
6     2 -11134709 1917752
```